# what is the probability of getting 3 males?

Tags: probability

> A family decides to buy $5$ dogs.  If the chances of picking a male and
>   female are equal, what is the probability of getting $3$ males?

my answer was $1/6$

Comment: Did you mean "exactly 3 males"?

Answer (score 3):

Well there is a 1/2 chance of getting a male, so if you want exactly 3 males, that means you will have 2 females.  Since they're both of probability 1/2, this comes out to $\frac{1}{2}^5$, but you have to multiply this by 5 choose 3=10 to account for all the different permutations, for a total of $\frac{1}{2}^5*10=0.3125$.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess that you answered $\frac 16$ because you counted $6$ possible outcomes, as follows:

$0$ males, $1$ male, $2$ males, $3$ males, $4$ males, $5$ males.

But these outcomes are not equally likely. Look at the probability of $6$ males,
for example. Half the time, when you buy the first dog, it is male.
And half of those times the second dog is male, too, so now we have only
$\frac14$ chance that the first two dogs are both male.
Buy a third dog, and the chance we now have three males is only half
the chance that the first two were male: $\frac18$.
By the time we have bought all $5$ dogs we have only $\frac{1}{32}$
chance to have $5$ males, not $\frac16$ as you would get if all
the above outcomes were equally likely.

If you count the outcomes using a set like the following,
then you can consider all outcomes equally likely. But there are $32$
possible outcomes in this set:

$FFFFF$, $FFFFM$, $FFFMF$, $FFMFF$, $FMFFF$, $MFFFF$, $FFFMM$, $FFMFM$, etc.

The dog-buying outcomes $FFMMM$, $FMMFM$, and $FMMMF$ are just a few of the ways
you can get three males.

Answer (score 1):

Let,

The probability of selecting $F$ in buying ONE dog  $= 0.5$.

The probability of selecting $M$ in buying ONE dog $= 0.5x$

Total probability for SINGLE buying $=(0.5+0.5x)$

Total probability for FIVE buyings $=(0.5+0.5x)^5$

[$(.5+.5x)^5 = 0.03125 + 0.15625 x + 0.3125 x^2 + \mathbf{0.3125 x^3} + 0.15625 x^4 + 0.03125 x^5$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%28%28.5%2B.5x%29%5E5%29)

The coefficient of $x^3$ is the probability of 3 Males in 5 buyings, that is $0.3125$.

From the expression you can also note other probabilities. Getting single male in 5 dogs is coefficient of $x$ and it is $0.1562$. Getting no male or getting all males both have equally low probabilities of just .03125.

It can also be noted that sum of all the coefficients is ONE.

Answer (score 0):

the probability of picking male or female are equal, and 5 are chosen, for a total of $2^5$ possibilities.  for $3$ of them to be male, need # of combinations of 3 into 5, or $5\choose 3$.  so answer is:

${{5\choose 3}\over{2^5}}={10\over 32}={5\over 16}$

Answer (score -2):

This is a binomial distribution with n=5, k=3, p=$\frac{1}{2}$.
$P=C^5_3\times(\frac{1}{2})^3\times(\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{5}{16}$

Comment: @Snark I am not a babysitter. helma can search it by him/herself